# Java, can't visualize output

Tags: java, output, visualizer

I am super new to programming and I'm studying for a test and don't understand the output of a piece of code.  I was hoping you could help me understand why the 4 is being printed at the end?

I threw the code in the Java visualizer site and I understand everything except why the line...
System.out.println(myScope.z); would print the number 4?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class ScopeTest {
   int z;

public static void main(String[] args){

  ScopeTest myScope = new ScopeTest();
  int z = 6;
  System.out.println(z);
  myScope.doStuff();
  System.out.println(z);
  System.out.println(myScope.z);
}

void doStuff() {
  int z = 5;
  doStuff2();
  System.out.println(z);
}

void doStuff2() {
  z=4;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping through code one line at a time is a good exercise to figure out what it is doing. You should do this with paper and pencil as well as with a debugger. So let's step through your code one line at a time in the order of execution. After each line of code, I'll explain what it does.

```
ScopeTest myScope = new ScopeTest();
```

Create a local reference variable named `myScope` and initialize it to an object.

```
int z = 6;
```

Create a local `int` variable named `z` and initialize it to `6`.

```
System.out.println(z);
```

Print the value of the local variable `z`.

```
myScope.doStuff();
```

Call `doStuff()` on the `myScope` object.

```
int z = 5;
```

Create a local variable `z` in `doStuff()` and initialize it to `5`.

```
doStuff2();
```

Call `doStuff2()`

```
z=4;
```

Set the **member field** named `z` to the value `4`. And then return control back to `doStuff()`.

```
System.out.println(z);
```

Print out the value of the local variable `z`. And then return control back to `main()`.

```
System.out.println(z);
```

Print out the value of the local variable `z`. (Remember we are back in `main()` now.

```
System.out.println(myScope.z);
```

Finally, print out the **member field** `z`. (Remember its value was set back in `doStuff2()`. This value is remembered because this `z` is a member variable.)

Answer (score 2):

1. `ScopeTest myScope = new ScopeTest();` initializes `myScope.z` to **0** (default value)
2. `myScope.doStuff();` sets `myScope.z` to **5** and calls `doStuff2()`
3. `doStuff2()` sets `myScope.z` to **4**.

The final result being 4. Key point is that the local `z` variables declared in the `main` and `doStuff()` methods have no bearing whatsoever on the `z` member variable declared in `ScopeTest`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Flow:

myScope.doStuff() --> 1. z=5 2. doStuff2() --> z=4

Answer (score 0):

You are calling dostuff() in main() method, there you have initialized z=5 which is its local variable z and not class variable z. so then you are calling **dostuff2()** in which you are **actually modifying class variable z=4**. That is why it is printing z=4 in last syestem.out.println(z). Hope this will help you understanding output.

Answer (score 0):

because In your code  `z` declared in the first line, is instance member (`this` context).

so when ever `doStuff2()` is called `this.z` is set to 4.

`//effectively
void doStuff2() {
  this.z=4;
}`

the variables `int z` declared inside the methods `main` and `doStuff()` are in `local context`.

and here, it only matters when the value of `z` in `this` context is set finally (which is inside `doStuff2()`).
Thus,

`System.out.println(z);  >> prints value of local variable z declared in main
 System.out.println(myScope.z); >> prints the value of instance (of ScopeTest which is myscope here) member z`